# can you choose the boto3 s3 protocol?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Apparently the normal s3uri protocol is all but deprecated. Is this what boto3 uses? can we select s3n or s3a which are the new preferred methods?

From AmazonS3 [wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3):

> A block-based filesystem backed by S3. Files are stored as blocks, just like they are in HDFS. This permits efficient implementation of renames. This filesystem requires you to dedicate a bucket for the filesystem - you should not use an existing bucket containing files, or write other files to the same bucket. The files stored by this filesystem can be larger than 5GB, but they are not interoperable with other S3 tools. Nobody is/should be uploading data to S3 via this scheme any more; it will eventually be removed from Hadoop entirely. Consider it (as of May 2016), deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a backend boto3 utilizes AWS S3 Rest API:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html

This is the only option available at the moment.

If you don't like the way boto3 works, consider crafting your own requests.