# Is it safe to read data with boto3 from S3 if that data had been written using Stocator in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, boto3, stocator

I have an application that uses [Stocator](https://github.com/CODAIT/stocator) as a connector for Spark. This application writes the data to the S3 cos bucket.

Now I am working on a service that's supposed to read that data from S3. According to this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798586/can-you-choose-the-boto3-s3-protocol), you cannot specify the uri/protocol that boto3 uses. Is it safe to read that data using the default protocol of S3 REST API?

The reason I am asking is that I have been told that reading data using S3A (another protocol) that has been written using Stocator could result in reading duplicates.

Comment: If S3A results in duplicates, that's because it was written with duplicates... boto3 would not dedupe the data, either. Also `s3a://` is  only a JVM hadoop-aws S3 SDK protocol, not boto, and the linked answer is 6 years old

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate more on how S3A is written with duplicates?

Comment: I haven't not reviewed the project you've linked to, but when you say "you've been told reading data written using Stocator could result in duplicates", then that is simply because **duplicates were written**. Boto3 wouldn't remove duplicated data when reading. That is not related to the "protocol", so I'm not sure why you're trying to find an "alternative one"